# ESXi: Storage Adapter Paths - Active/Standby to Active/Active

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage

We have a couple of servers acting as VM hosts (ESXi v5.1) and they are connected to a Dell MD3220 SAS Array (2 cables each, split across 2 controllers).

We've just noticed that multipath wasn't working, and digging deeper it turns out we'd not mapped the second Port Identifier in each server's HBA card to a Host in the array management software (MDSM).

Mapping these Port Identifiers to a host has enabled a second path in ESXi, however this current configuration differs slightly from near-identical system that we have already configured. In this reference system, the two paths are marked as **Active (I/O)** and **Active**, whereas in this current system, the paths are described as **Active (I/O)** and **Standby**.

We've tested this current configuration and it works fine - the standby path is switched to Active (I/O) as soon as the original path is broken.

*However, I'm curious to know the difference in behaviour and how to make the systems match.*

FYI: The original system only differs from the current system insofar as the server model is slightly different; they are connecting to identical array and are running identical versions of ESXi v5.1. The only difference (I assume) is the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that with Active-Active both paths are being used for live traffic, this means you have essentially twice the bandwidth to your array, with Active-Passive only one link is carrying live traffic with the other ready to take over as required.

This may well be a simple path-policy issue, look at a single datastore's configuration, if you look at it's path data you'll see the path usage policy - I tend to use SATP_RR which is the round-robin variant but this may be slightly different for your storage (I'm no Dell expert sorry). If you wish to set this to be a new default then take a look at [THIS](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017760) link.

Comment: IIRC we did nothing special to tweak the paths in the original system. Both are set in the Most Recently Used configuration. I did try changing the current system to Round Robin, but it didn't appear to make the second path active. Also, I thought that Active(I/O) meant that the path was active and being used, which I assume is separate to simply Active..... though I'm not sure of the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Active-active is called NIC Teaming, meaning both NIC/paths are being actively used. You get twice the bandwidth. It acts similar to an ether-channel / port channel on a switch.

Active-Passive is a Fail-over system, meaning one NIC/path works and one NIC is on stand-by. If the primary one fails, the secondary one will take over.

If you need the extra bandwidth, the first option is recommended, otherwise you can safely go with the second one.